# Blockgroup-level data on industries and occupations in California

Tags: usa, geospatial, industry

The [American Community Survey (ACS)](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/guidance/training-presentations/acs-block-groups.html) provides some information on people's work places on the block-group level, that is spatial data a bit more detailed than at zip-code level.

Do you know any other sources for data at the block-group level or similar detailed spatial data that gives away information on the industries and occupations people work in?